# add style to the last child of the last child

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

[image]

This is an image of my code. I have a `footer-container` inside which there are several `footer-content` classes, each of which contains a `<p>` tag and then a `<span>` tag. I want to apply a style to `span` of the last `footer-content`

This is what it looks like I want to remove the last `-` after `risk analysis` 
[image]

I have tried this

`.footer-container:last-child :last-child  {
  display: none;
}`

but this hides all the span tags

Comment: space missing before the first `:last-child`

Comment: Get a browsers tool called SelectorGadget. You can narrow it down to the specific element and it'll tell you the CSS selectors you need to style that specific element.  Will help you learn

Comment: `:last-child` asks *Am I the last child of my parent?*, not *Who is my last child element?*

Comment: Instead of creating those `span.footer-dash` at all, you can do that using CSS only: `.footer-content:not(:last-child):after { content: "-"; }` Apply styling as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That selector should be

```
.footer-container :last-child :last-child { ... }
```

(space after `.footer-container`)

Answer (score 4):

**Edit**: To create those dashes between your entries, instead of creating those `span.footer-dash` at all, you can do that using CSS only:

```
.footer-content:not(:last-child) .footer-item::after { 
  content: "-";
  color: #666;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
```

Apply styling as needed. The selector makes sure the dash isn't added after the last element at all, so no need to hide anything if it's not there in the first place.

---

`:last-child` asks ***Am I the last child of my parent?***, not *Who is my last child element?* (which your selector suggests you think).

So either use the descendant selector (space):

```
.footer-container :last-child :last-child  {
  display: none;
}
```

or use it on the correct *child* elements:

```
.footer-content:last-child :last-child  {
  display: none;
}
```

Please note that usage of `:last-child` should be made carefully as it ties your stuff very closely to the DOM structure (which you might want to change later).

I'd suggest you change it like this:

```
.footer-content:last-child .footer-dash  {
  display: none;
}
```

> The `:last-child` CSS pseudo-class represents the last element among a group of sibling elements.

```
/* Selects any <p> that is the last element
   among its siblings */
p:last-child {
  color: lime;
}
```

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child

Answer (score 1):

I think this should help you

```css
.footer-container .footer-content:last-child{
 background-color:red;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Css practice</title>

</head>
<body>
   
   <div class="footer-container">
 <div class="footer-content">
 <p><span>Section Number 1</span></p>
 </div>
 <div class="footer-content">
 <p><span>Section Number 2</span></p>
 </div>
 <div class="footer-content">
 <p><span>Section Number 3</span></p>
 </div>
 <div class="footer-content">
 <p><span>Section Number 4</span></p>
 </div>
 
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add:

```
.footer-container .footer-content:last-child .footer-dash  {
  display: none;
}
```

As per the **Q** - *I want to remove the last - after risk analysis*

This will just work fine for you. This will also prevent other elements from being affected by your `:last-child` CSS selection if you change the order of the content inside the `.footer-content`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.footer-container .footer-content:last-child span {
    /* css here */
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This code should work:

```css
.footer-container:last-child>:last-child  {
  display: none;
}
```

Using a space will target **all** the elements that are last children **inside** `.footer-container:last-child`, while using `>` will target the last child of 
`.footer-container:last-child` only.

Comment: *Using a space will target all the elements* your selector is not using a space, though.

Comment: Yes. Using a space will target all last children (grandchildren included) of the last child, instead of only the last child of the last child.